# Getting: INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "" when trying to date_parse a string formatted date

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, dateparser

Query:

```
SELECT date_parse(start_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
FROM sql_question_five_2 ;
```

date format looks like this in csv: 20210531
being read into table as string.

Have tried a few different things to get it to convert to a date YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date_parse` expects all inputs to look like the format string, if they don't it will throw an error. You can do something like this to avoid the problem:

```
SELECT IF(start_date = '', NULL, date_parse(start_date, '%Y/%m/%d'))
FROM sql_question_five_2
```

This guards against the case where the string is empty, which is the case when you get the error. If you have other strings that don't conform to the format you would have to guard against those too.

If that is the case you can use the [`TRY`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/conditional.html#try) function which captures errors and returns `NULL`:

```
SELECT TRY(date_parse(start_date, '%Y/%m/%d'))
FROM sql_question_five_2
```

Comment: This worked once i removed the /s
SELECT IF(start_date = '', NULL, date_parse(start_date, '%Y/%m/%d'))
FROM sql_question_five_2

The results came back looking like this: 2019-01-17 00:00:00.000

My next step was to create a temp table to further format the date with this:
SELECT DATE(start_date) AS start_date
FROM "test"."question_five_temp_table";

Which gave me these results: 
2021-01-01

Comment: The next part which im still trying to figure out is now to get a column with the difference in day from a start_date and end_date. 

I have tried DATEDIFF function, but Athena doesn't seem to recognize the function in the SELECT statement?

SELECT
DATE(start_date) AS start_date,
DATE(end_date) AS end_date
FROM "test"."question_five_temp_table"
WHERE end_date >= CAST('2021-05-31' AS DATE)
AND start_date <= CAST('2021-05-01' AS DATE);

Answer (score 0):

Your format string needs to match the source value. Your source doesn’t have /‘s in it so your format string shouldn’t either

Comment: Tried removing the /s to match source value as suggested:

SELECT date_parse(start_date, '%Y%m%d') AS start_date
FROM sql_question_five_2;

Now it runs without error, but also no results?

Comment: So what result do you get if you run: SELECT start_date, date_parse(start_date, '%Y%m%d') AS start_date1 FROM sql_question_five_2